# How can i save the facebook profile picture to my local folder using facebook graph api in codeigniter?

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-graph-api

I have the sdk and facebook login is working fine. I am getting the user details without any problem and problem is only with the profile picture.

Comment: Could you place some code in your OP would be use full to see.

Answer (score 0):

If you are geting user profile image then use following function 
It work for me

```
    $this->save_profile_photo($socialUser['image']);

    function save_profile_photo($link) {
        if ($link) {
            $img = file_get_contents($link);
            $imagename = "/profile" .  . '-' . date('y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.jpg';
            $file = base_url(PROFILE_IMAGE) . '/' . $imagename;
            file_put_contents($file, $img);
        }
    }
```